# Elasticsearch and IPv6

Tags: elasticsearch, ipv6

Does anyone know if Elasticsearch supports IPv6 range aggregation?
More specifically, I am looking for IPv6 nested aggregation.

If not Elasticsearch, then perhaps I can do this with other tools?

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elasticsearch doesn't support IPv6 addresses yet. This is written at the very bottom in documentation:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ip.html

Following that, IPv6 aggregations cannot be done too.